# Only seeing half my RAM in BIOS and OS

Tags: linux, memory, bios

I have 4 sticks of Patriot 4GB([link](https://www.lambda-tek.com/Patriot-Memory-PSD34G1333KH~sh/B552402)) and there are 4 slots on my Gigabyte MB([link](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-EP43T-UD3L-rev-14#ov)).

As you can tell by the MB, this is an old machine, originally it had Windows on it but the last couple of years it has had an array of different linux distros currently Kubuntu 18.10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

I know at the start I was seeing the full 16G but do not know when that changed but realised recently that only 8GB is showing in the BIOS and available to my OS.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Update BIOS to most recent version
2. Reset CMOS to optimised defaults
3. Take out MB battery and put back in after 5mins
4. I have tried each of the slots by themselves and they all work. I have tried each of the sticks by themselves and they work. When I have one stick it only shows 2GB, 2 sticks 4GB, 4 sticks 8GB

I have been trawling the internet for a solution so any suggestions or thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You've pretty clearly tested that each ram stick is only 2GB, are you absolutely certain they're supposed to be 4GB sticks? Do you have any photos of them, especially the labels / writing?

Comment: Thanks @Xen2050 the 4GB printed on the stick has misled me, as David has pointed out below they come in a 4GB pair 2x2G

Comment: That is a very deceptive webpage too, literally says *"...4GB DDR3 1333MHz memory module"*, implying one singular module, but the 2x2G is buried in the specs there... like fine print.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two 4GB kits, for a total memory of 8GB. The 8GB you are showing is all of your RAM. Read the link you pasted carefully -- it explains that these are 4GB kits that contain two sticks, each 2GB.

> Memory layout (modules x size)    2 x 2 GB

Comment: Thanks, I bought these a long time ago so can't remember that they came in pairs, and its a bit deceiving that each stick has 4GB printed on it even though under it has 2x2GB kit in smaller writing